# Powerapps sort combobox first item will be todays date

Tags: sorting, lookup, powerapps-canvas

i have managed to populate a combobox in PowerApps with multiple column items i would like to have the first item (Date_by_Day) = today i have played around with Sort(),Ascending, Date_by_Day = Today() but no luck

```
Distinct(RP_Weekly_Period_Dates_SPList,Date_by_Day & " : " & 'Week 
(Long)' & " - " & 'Period (Long)' & " - " & Year)
```

Not sure if this possible but any suggestions would be great

Comment: please elaborate further. What kind of data is the Date_by_day column (date & time, date only, text, etc.)? Does the data contain only past dates or today and future dates only? When you say 'no luck', what were the exact results?

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, The date_by_Day is a date only sharepoint 'Date' Column, the dates are a list everyday from 2020 to 2030 i require the first item in the combobox list Date_byDay to = Today

i am stuck on how to get something like SortbyColumn(Distinct(RP_Weekly_Period_Dates_SPList,Date_by_Day & " : " & 'Week 
(Long)' & " - " & 'Period (Long)' & " - " & Year),Date_by_Day = Today(),Ascending)

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to achieve this. From the user's perspective, the best experience would be using a date picker. If you insist on using a combobox, at least the dates should be sorted (2020 to 2030 or vice versa).

Comment: my advice would be to sort the dates ascending, and set Today in the combobox.Default property.

Comment: on the other hand I tested your formula and it worked for me, returning a list of dates where today is the first one, the rest sorted first to last. Perhaps the issue is that the data you get from SharePoint have a time value with a timezone offset. So, in your sort expression, you have to use DateValue(), like: DateValue(Date_by_Day) = DateValue(Today()).

Comment: Thank you, absolutely agree datepicker is the best way but i need to only allow 'Fridays' to be selected i cannot seem to achieve this with datepicker

Comment: I'd still stick with the datepicker, enforcing the Fridays-only rule by checking the input in the OnChange formula. If not Friday, you can use Reset(Self) to delete their choice and Notify() to explain.

Comment: Thank you! I do admit that does look better and tidies up the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datepicker is the best way with error message if any other day is selected